# Quantum Random Generator outputs pieces of PI

Tags: python, random

This is a curiosity as a follow up from [Purely Random Numbers Generator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/275083/purely-random-numbers-generator)

```
import quantumrandom as qr

with open("piDigits.txt", 'r') as f:
    pidecimals = f.read()
f.close()

maxrange = int(input("Enter Maxmimum of Range "))
count = 0

for i in range (0,maxrange):
    myx = qr.randint()
    print(f"Quantum Number {myx}")
    decimalstring = str(myx)
    substring1 = decimalstring[2:7]
    substring2 = decimalstring[7:12]
    substring3 = decimalstring[12:17]
    if substring1 in pidecimals:
        count += 1
        print(f"Quantum digit sequence {substring1} found in Pi")
    if substring2 in pidecimals:
        count += 1
        print(f"Quantum digit sequence {substring2} found in Pi")
    if substring3 in pidecimals:
        count += 1
        print(f"Quantum digit sequence {substring3} found in Pi")
print(f"Quantum digit sequences found in Pi {count} times out of {3*maxrange}")
```

Sample Output

```
Enter Maxmimum of Range 10
Quantum Number 1.7061112382696269
Quantum digit sequence 70611 found in Pi
Quantum digit sequence 12382 found in Pi
Quantum digit sequence 69626 found in Pi
Quantum Number 5.202105745021744
Quantum digit sequence 20210 found in Pi
Quantum digit sequence 57450 found in Pi
Quantum digit sequence 21744 found in Pi
Quantum Number 0.7571526665140764
Quantum digit sequence 75715 found in Pi
Quantum digit sequence 26665 found in Pi
Quantum digit sequence 14076 found in Pi
Quantum Number 5.667963683527886
Quantum digit sequence 66796 found in Pi
Quantum digit sequence 36835 found in Pi
Quantum digit sequence 27886 found in Pi
Quantum Number 9.458762493324178
Quantum digit sequence 45876 found in Pi
Quantum digit sequence 24933 found in Pi
Quantum digit sequence 24178 found in Pi
Quantum Number 9.17463950560769
Quantum digit sequence 17463 found in Pi
Quantum digit sequence 95056 found in Pi
Quantum digit sequence 0769 found in Pi
Quantum Number 1.8011749446860457
Quantum digit sequence 80117 found in Pi
Quantum digit sequence 49446 found in Pi
Quantum digit sequence 86045 found in Pi
Quantum Number 0.5055313954375524
Quantum digit sequence 50553 found in Pi
Quantum digit sequence 13954 found in Pi
Quantum digit sequence 37552 found in Pi
Quantum Number 2.6465247577630273
Quantum digit sequence 64652 found in Pi
Quantum digit sequence 47577 found in Pi
Quantum digit sequence 63027 found in Pi
Quantum Number 0.8364995803768979
Quantum digit sequence 83649 found in Pi
Quantum digit sequence 95803 found in Pi
Quantum digit sequence 76897 found in Pi
Quantum digit sequences found in Pi 30 times out of 30
```

Come on, this has to be more than coincidence! Is the code wrong somehow?!?!?

Comment: "is finding a string of random digits in the digits of Pi a coincidence" isn't particularly a code review question. Consider instead Cross Validated.

Comment: Consider: what is the probability that X (5 random digits) is found in Y (1 million random digits)? My math is rusty, but I assume it's nearly 1.0. Given that, why are you surprised/impressed by the fact than a different collection of 1M random digits (Pi is [conjectured](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2015/03/12/digits-of-pi.html#:~:text=The%20distribution%20of%20digits%20of,of%20digits%2C%20and%20so%20forth.) to be that) contains nearly every 5-digit sequence? [Pi is missing 8 of the possible sequences, so when `Y = Pi` the empirically observed probability is 999988/999996.]

Comment: If you don't know whether the code does what you want it to do, we can't review it.

Answer (score 3):

• The code presented lacks a [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring) stating a purpose.
• There is triplicated code in the `for` loop:
  Use a nested loop.
  Better yet: Use a single loop, or motivate "times 3"
• The first parameter in `range(0, beyond)` is the implied in the preferable
  `range(beyond)`
• The iteration variable `i` is unused.
  The conventional name for the variable receiving unused results is `_`
• I'd think "number of tries" more useful than "Maxmimum of Range" [sic].